# How do you create a UITextView with blocks and zoom in effect (like the Essayist App)

Tags: swift, textview, zooming, uitextview, pinchzoom

I would like to achieve the zoom in effect like how the Essayist app implements it. I would also like to know how to split a textview into chunks/paragraphs/blocks, just like the app. I really don't have a clue as to how I can achieve the zoom-in effect (and keep the text sharp as well) and how to split the text view into chunks.

Zoom in effect (Essayist):

[image]

Paragraphs/chunks/blocks of text for the textview (Essayist):
[image]

Comment: This looks like a pdf to me. How did this text appear in the app ? Is it something you type or import ?

Comment: You just type text in the app, like with google docs. I contacted the devs, and they told me that they just use swift and uikit

Comment: Swift and UIKit is quite broad. Would be interesting if you can understand what specific technology they used ScrollView, TextView is probably my next bet. And how does the zoom interaction happen ? Are you pinching or this is happening automatically ?

Comment: I'm pinching to zoom in/out. I'm going to try adding multiple NSTextViews to one NSLayoutManager

Comment: @AadiAnand did you find any solution for that?

Comment: No I didn't :( 

I suggest you use codementor.com and get some help from some devs about potential workarounds/solutions. I've abandoned the project because of other commitments, but mainly because I found implementing this sort of functionality in my app to be extremely difficult. Do let me know if you manage to figure it out though – that would be interesting to say the least!

Comment: Unfortunately `NSLayoutManager` can use multiple text containers on iOS only when the text is non-editable. You can approach this either by creating your own CoreText implementation or by creating a text view which floats in a `UIScrollView` and use exclusion paths and custom drawing to fake the page changes.